# Angular won't let me put expressions inside of <timer> element attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I am using AngularJS and angular-timer (http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/). For some reason, I cannot get something like `<timer some-attr="{[ some expression ]}" />` to work properly.

(I have Angular configured to use {[ and ]}, because I use Jinja2 in my backend which uses {{ }} and conflicts with Angular.)

It just throws this error in my JS console:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '[' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{[ countdown.time ]}] starting at [[ countdown.time ]}].
```

Why is this happening? Other expressions in the actual code (e.g. between `<timer> </timer>`) work just fine.

You can see a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d3xbs263/3/

The error can be seen in your JS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error seems to actually be that the attribute you are using already evaluates its contents as an expression. You would want to do something like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="countdown" ng-controller="CountdownCtrl as countdown">
        <!-- No brackets or expression needed -->
        <timer interval="1000" end-time="time">
            <h3 style="color: #9E75E3;">How long until Pony Time?</h3>
            <div class="numbers" id="count2" style="text-align: center;"></div>
            <div class="numbers" id="dday">{[ days ]}</div>
            <div class="title" id="days">Day{[ daysS ]}</div>
            <div class="numbers" id="dhour">{[ hours ]}</div>
            <div class="title" id="hours">Hour{[ hoursS ]}</div>
            <div class="numbers" id="dmin">{[ minutes ]}</div>
            <div class="title" id="minutes">Minute{[ minutesS ]}</div>
            <div class="numbers" id="dsec">{[ seconds ]}</div>
            <div class="title" id="seconds">Second{[ secondsS ]}</div>
            <h5>The next episode airs at 11:30 AM Eastern Time on Saturday</h5>
        </timer>
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3xbs263/2/)</kbd>

---

P.S. Your fiddle wasn't working because you needed to change the Frameworks and Extensions to `No wrap - in <body>`

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Putting the string "countdown.time" in there makes it think that it is counting down to the time "countdown.time", which is obviously not a UNIX timestamp. So instead, it ignores that attribute and just begins counting up from 0 like it does by default.

Comment: @AppleDash actually, this does solve the problem, however your declaration of the variable is incorrect in your controller.  Instead of `this.time` you have `$scope.time`, which means `time` *isn't* a property of `countdown`.  either change to `this`, or use `time` in the HTML, along with the correction in this answer (which is to not interpolate the variable in an expression).

Comment: @Claies Aha, it all makes sense now. Thank you!